# Spell check multiple languages at the same time, at the same input field?

Tags: high-sierra, spellcheck

Is there an option to somehow combine multiple languages at the same spell check "session"? Form what I can find under Keyboard > Text it seems that there are only two options
1) Chose one specific language
2) Allow to detect language by text that is written

I do often mix words from multiple languages and it is very annoying that I have text that has red line under words. I do not want to turn off spellcheck entirely. I still need to verify that what I have written is correct. I just need to combo my preferred languages.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do for apps that use the Apple facilities is to go to system preferences/keyboard/text/spelling/setup (at the bottom of the list) and check the boxes for only those languages you want to check, and then set it to "automatic".

How well it works for your particular requirements can only be determined by testing.  As far as I know, multilingual only works with languages for which dictionaries are provided by Apple.

Some apps like MS Word have their own spellcheck systems.

Comment: I have already tried this option. The automatic option detects only one language from text. The weird thing is, I started to enter text in one language, spell check worked for that language, continued by entering text in another and suddenly whole texts gets validated in language that last piece of text was in.

Comment: What are the languages you are checking?

Comment: Latvian, English. How does it matter, is there any difference in functionallity?

Comment: Yes, there is, unfortunately 3rd party dictionaries never work with multilingual as far as I know, and apple doesn't provide Latvian.